# How to display the record from the last month of the specified quarter within the current year?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named nca_totals.

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | 
+----------+-----------+------------+
|       17 | 8000      | 2015-01-01 | 
|       18 | 2000      | 2015-04-01 |
|       19 | 6000      | 2015-07-02 |
|       20 | 2000      | 2015-01-22 | 
|       21 | 6000      | 2015-03-02 |
|       22 | 5000      | 2015-06-01 | 
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to display all the rows who belong on the 1st Quarter within the current year and the last month of the quarter. For example, I want to return the month of March(2015-03-01) from the first quarter. On the next quarter 2nd quarter, the month of June(2015-06-01) must be displayed.

So far, I've come with this query to display all the record belongs to the 1st quarter but it displays all the month on that quarter in which this not what I wanted, Just the last month on that quarter

```
SELECT * FROM nca_totals WHERE QUARTER(nca_date) = 1 AND year(nca_date) = year('2015-01-01');
```

But something wrong with this query because it displays the following:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | 
+----------+-----------+------------+
|       17 | 8000      | 2015-01-01 | 
|       20 | 2000      | 2015-01-22 | 
|       21 | 6000      | 2015-03-02 |
|       22 | 5000      | 2015-06-01 | 
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Here's what I want to output on my query :

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| total_id | nca_total | nca_date   | 
+----------+-----------+------------+
|       21 | 6000      | 2015-03-02 |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

How to process it's month to get the last month from the 1st quarter? Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Instead of `QUARTER`, use the `MONTH` function …?

Comment: Do you want 2015-06-01 or not?

Comment: No. I want '2015-03-01' if we say we want the 1st quarter. But of the 2nd quarter.. the date to display must be '2015-06-01'. The point is The query must display the the last month of the given quarter. So, if I say 1st quarter, this referring to March. 2nd Quarter referrring to June and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The last month of the quarters are constant will always be (3,6,9,12) so you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM nca_totals WHERE MONTH(nca_date) in (3,6,9,12) AND year(nca_date) = year('2015-01-01');
```